# Telegram bot inline keyboard via AppScript

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I am making a Telegram bot using Appscript and I want to copy/send message with an inline_keyboard but when I send the URL I get an invalid parameter error and I don't know what is wrong, because everything worked until I add the reply_markup parameter.

```
function enviarMnesjePruebaCanal() {//ENVIAR MENSAJE
  var urlusuarioconid = "tg://userid?=" + miID
  var keyboard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [
        {
          "text": "Usuario",
          "url": urlusuarioconid
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
  var url = telegramUrl + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + miID + '&text=' + "texto" + "&reply_markup=" + JSON.stringify(keyboard);
  Logger.log(url);
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

`
This is my code and this is what I send to telegram and what I get back:
(I have deleted the data of my bot and my id for obvious reasons, but that part is ok because when I run it without the last part it sends me the message)

[image]

I have already tried several things and they all give the same problem, I don't know if anyone can help me or see what could be happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `reply_markup` containing non-url tokens.

You should encode that part of the url using `encodeURIComponent()`

---

Change the code to:

```js
function enviarMnesjePruebaCanal() {
    var myID = 123456;
    var urlusuarioconid = "tg://userid?=" + myID
    var keyboard = {
        "inline_keyboard": [
            [
                {
                    "text": "Usuario",
                    "url": urlusuarioconid
                }
            ]
        ]
    };
    
    var url = telegramUrl + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + myID + '&text=' + "texto" + "&reply_markup=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(keyboard));
    Logger.log(url);
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

The important change here is adding the `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(keyboard))
```